# Message callback synchronization error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

In my extension's content script, I request data from background.js like so:

```
fireOnNewTopic ();  // Initial run on cold start or full reload.

window.addEventListener ("hashchange", fireOnNewTopic,  false);

function fireOnNewTopic () {
/*-- For the pages we want, location.hash will contain values
    like: "#!newtopic/{group title}"
*/
  if (location.hash) {
    var locHashParts    = location.hash.split ('/');
    if (locHashParts.length > 1  &&  locHashParts[0] == '#!newtopic') {
        var subjectStr  = '';
        var bodyStr  = '';
        switch (locHashParts[1]) {
            case 'opencomments-site-discussions':
            chrome.extension.sendMessage({name:"domain"},
                function(response)
                {
                subjectStr = response.domain;   
                });
            chrome.extension.sendMessage({name:"url"},
                function(response)
                {
                bodyStr = "URL of last page visited: " +                        response.url;   
                });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (subjectStr && bodyStr) {
            runPayloadCode (subjectStr, bodyStr);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, since sendMessage() runs asynchronously with the callback, at the time the code reaches runPayloadCode(), subjectStr and bodyStr are still null, since the code in background.js hasn't completed. What's the best way to synchronize the code so that subjectStr and bodyStr are filled in by the time runPayloadCode() is called?

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783093/any-better-way-to-combine-multiple-callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on what Sudarshan said about combining the two requests into one (sorry, need code so couldn't just comment) here's what you could do...
**send**

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({url: true, domain:true}, function(response) {
  console.debug('The url is "'+response.url+'" and the domain is"'+response.domain+'"');
  if (repsone.url && response.domain) {
            runPayloadCode (subjectStr, "URL of last page visited: " + response.domain);
        }
});
```

or, if you wanted it more like your case way for some reason, maybe this is the sorta thing you'd like...

```
    if(location.hash) {
        var locHashParts = location.hash.split('/');
        if(locHashParts.length > 1 && locHashParts[0] == '#!newtopic') {
            var subjectStr = '';
            var bodyStr = '';
            var request = {};
            switch(locHashParts[1]) {
            case 'opencomments-site-discussions':

                request = {
                    url: true,
                    domain: true
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }

            chrome.extension.sendMessage(request, function(response) {
                console.debug('The url is "' + response.url + '" and the domain is"' + response.domain + '"');
                if(repsone.url && response.domain) {
                    runPayloadCode(subjectStr, "URL of last page visited: " + response.domain);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

**listen**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var response = {};
    if(request.url) {
        response.url = "someURL";
    }
    if(request.domain) {
        response.domain = "someDomain";
    }
    sendResponse(response);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I can combine the two requests into one and that part works fine, but the basic issue of async operation is still shooting me down; see comments below.

Comment: @PAEz: thanks again for making it clear, i am thankful for your efforts in correcting me... thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
case 'opencomments-site-discussions':
chrome.extension.sendMessage({
    name: "domain"
},

function (response) {
    subjectStr = response.domain;
  if(subjectStr){
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({
        name: "url"
    },

    function (response) {
        bodyStr = "URL of last page visited: " + response.url;
        if (bodyStr) {
            runPayloadCode(subjectStr, bodyStr);
        }
    });
}
});
```

However, can't you merge both message's `chrome.extension.sendMessage({name: "url"})` and `chrome.extension.sendMessage({name: "domain"})` into single message(Because i see them independent) and eliminate multiple nesting?

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of asynchronous operation. If I set a breakpoint in the content script to allow the it to wait for the listener to respond, of course, it works; otherwise, it reaches the break; before data is returned.

Comment: As per PAEz's suggestion, I replaced the two sendMessage() calls with the following and like I said, as long as I force the content script to wait awhile, I get both the URL and domain back:        chrome.extension.sendMessage({url: true, domain: true},
            function(response)
         {
         subjectStr = response.domain; 
         bodyStr = "URL of last page visited: " +       response.url; 
        });

Comment: Just put `if (subjectStr && bodyStr) { runPayloadCode (subjectStr, bodyStr); }` in the response function